Unable to build kernel in OpenCL
I am trying out OpenCL (self learning) and recently decided to try out writing a Prime Calculation program but when I tried to build it, it would failed
Here is the CL listing
bool isPrime(long long number)
{
    if (number < 2)
        return false;

    if (number == 2 || number == 3)
        return true;

    //This was missing initially. 
    if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 3 == 0)
        return false;

    if (fmod((double)number, 2) == 0.0)
        return false;

    long long sqrtNumber = (long long)sqrt((double)number);
    long long dx = 4;

    for (long long i = 5; i <= sqrtNumber; i += dx) {
        if (fmod((double)number, i) == 0.0)
            return false;
        dx = -(dx - 6);
    }

    return true;
}

kernel void PrimeCalculator( long long StartValue, long long EndValue, global long long* CountOfPrimes, global bool* PrimeList)
{
    size_t ID = get_global_id(0);
    local int totalPrimesForThisGroup;

    printf("ID: %i\n", ID);
    if (ID < get_global_size(0)) //Ensure the value is within range
    {
        //Now check if the value is prime
       *(PrimeList+ID) = isPrime(ID+1); //ID is 0 based
    }

    // wait for all threads to finish
    work_group_barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    //Add up all the primes found.
    atomic_add(&totalPrimesForThisGroup, *(PrimeList+ID));
    // wait for all threads to finish
    work_group_barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    printf("Total primes found so far : %d\n", totalPrimesForThisGroup);

    //Now get save the total to the CountOfPrimes
    if (ID == 0)
    {
        atomic_add(CountOfPrimes, totalPrimesForThisGroup);
        printf("Total primes found in zero : %d\n", totalPrimesForThisGroup);
    }
}

But when I tried to build it with the following command below, it would failed and report an access violation error when I tried to build
    try
    {
        CompiledProgram = clCreateProgramWithSource(ContextToUse, 1, &source_ptr, NULL, &errNum);
        if (isError(errNum, "Failed to create program."))
        {
            throw std::exception(getCompilationError(CompiledProgram, DeviceID).c_str());
        }

        errNum = clBuildProgram(CompiledProgram, 1, &DeviceID, "-cl-std=CL2.0", NULL, NULL); <- This is where it will throw the access violation error.
        if (isError(errNum, "Failed to build program."))
        {   
            throw std::exception(getCompilationError(CompiledProgram, DeviceID).c_str());
        }

        CompiledKernel = clCreateKernel(CompiledProgram, kernelName, &errNum);
        if (isError(errNum, "Failed to create kernel."))
        {
            throw std::exception(getCompilationError(CompiledProgram, DeviceID).c_str());
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        clReleaseProgram(CompiledProgram);
        throw e;
    }

I am unable to determine why it would failed at clBuildProgram.
The only other error I got on the console is
Device to use: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 <- this is from my own debugging
Binary Instruction seen with illegal int type. Legalization support missing. Inst opcode:15

I am unable to determine what is wrong with my cl codes since the error message doesn't give me any idea at all what is wrong.

Have you tested that you have a working OpenCL runtime environment? If not, try running clinfo and see if your OpenCL device is reporting properly. Are the cl_khr_int64_base_atomics and cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics extensions supported and enabled?

Yeah I do, managed to run the clint and a basic Hello world.
and both cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics  are supported. Not sure how to check if they enabled though.

I just tried to run a floating point OpenCL benchmark program I wrote on my Skylake HD Graphics 530, a generation earlier than yours, otherwise very similar. It failed to run correctly. I think the platform may be buggy. If you have an Nvidia discrete GPU handy, try running it on that instead. Not sure if the atomics extensions mentioned earlier need #pragmas in the code or not, but that's something else to look out for, along with the OpenCL version you've told it to use.

@SimonGoater thank you for your answer. Sorry for the late reply. I guess I will have to wait until later to check if my codes will compile on an Nvidia or a newer Intel GPU. Maybe I should try AMD GPU instead.

If you post some complete code, I can run it on my working OpenCL SDE and dGPU if you like.
